# jQuery token input not display data tags rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the `jQuery token-input` gem in my rails application. I have got it working as expected except for the data load part. When I create a `plan` with multiple `materials`, and save it, it creates the record like it is suppose to.

When I go back to edit that plan, no materials are showing up. However, the data is being pre-loaded in the browser as I can see from the source code seen below.

```
<input data-tokeninput="{&quot;collection&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;goal&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;material_type&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;sharing&quot;:false,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;unit_id&quot;:null,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2018-04-24T21:40:58.000Z&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2018-04-24T21:40:58.000Z&quot;,&quot;grade_id&quot;:6,&quot;user_id&quot;:1,&quot;subject_id&quot;:6,&quot;attachment_file_name&quot;:null,&quot;attachment_content_type&quot;:null,&quot;attachment_file_size&quot;:null,&quot;attachment_updated_at&quot;:null}]}" type="text" name="plan[material_tokens]" id="plan_material_tokens" style="display: none;">
```

Does anybody know why this is not displaying the data in the field?

**Plans.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#plan_material_tokens').tokenInput('/materials.json', { propertyToSearch: 'title' });
  prePopulate: $('#plan_material_tokens').data('load')
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @plan do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :material_tokens, "Materials" %>
    <%= form.text_field :material_tokens, data: { load: @plan.materials }%>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Materials controller**(where it is pulling the json data from)

```
def index
  @materials = current_user.materials

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @materials.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else having this issue here is the solution that helped me.
Instead of having the data loader called `load`, change it to `pre` as seen below.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :material_tokens, "Materials" %>
  <%= form.text_field :material_tokens, data: { pre: @plan.materials.to_json }%>
</div>
```

**plans.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#plan_material_tokens').tokenInput('/materials.json', { propertyToSearch: 'title' })
  zindex: 6000
  allowCustomEntry: false
  preventDuplicates: true
  prePopulate: $("#plan_material_tokens").data('pre')
```

I am going to do further research on why this is the case and will follow up in this answer.